# Как отловить событие добавления маркеров?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как отловить и обработать событие добавления маркеров?

Нужно, чтобы при этом в выдвигающуюся колонку добавлялась запись:

[image: Пример]

Comment: Как уже пытались решить, в чем возникла проблема?

Comment: В google.maps есть [туториалы](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=ru) и описание [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=ru)